# Boost python, returning a class from a method of another class

Tags: python, c++, boost

My problem is that I have two classes like this

```
class B{
public:
    double x,y;
}

class A{
public:
    B foo();
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(interestingLib){
    class_<A>("A")
        .def("foo", &A::foo)
    ;
    class_<B>("B")
        .def_readonly("x",&B::x)
        .def_readonly("y",&B::y)
    ;
}
```

in my python script I call my function `foo` and get the return, after that I want to see the member variable `x` like this

```
A = interestingLib.A
B = A.foo()
B.x
```

but I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'`

could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Did that code even compile? `A::foo()` is private. So, are `B::x` and `B::y`. `&B.x` does not make sense. Neither does `&B.y`. Can you please post code that you are actually using?

Comment: Please, provide implementation of `A::foo()` method

Comment: @crayzeewulf Corrected the code a bit. My code is in two files and a lot of lines. Should I still post it here?

Comment: Please try: `A = interestingLib.A()` (notice `()`). You need to create an object of class A before using it. Also, avoid using variable names that are the same as names of classes.

Answer (score 2):

In python you should use

```
A = interestingLib.A()
```

instead of

```
A = interestingLib.A
```

This code `A = interestingLib.A` assign to `A` object of type `Boost.Python.class`. And with `A = interestingLib.A()` you create object of type `A` with default constructor.